# How to convert an url to an IP address

Tags: raku

Right now I'm learning the Perl 6 language, and I'd like to know how to convert an url to an IP address

It seems to me that the gethostbyname function does not exist.

Comment: FWIW, a `P5gethostbyname` module that exports `gethostbyname` with Perl 5 semantics, is in the works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gethostbyname is obsoleted by now. `getaddrinfo` is used instead. You will have to use [the NativeCall API](https://docs.perl6.org/language/nativecall#Short_Tutorial_on_calling_a_C_function) to call this POSIX function. The example included in the NativeCall page addresses precisely this problem.